# Медленно работает перемножение матриц java

Tags: java, алгоритм

Добрый день.
Написал код, вычисляющий остаток от деления n-ного числа Фибоначчи на вводимое из консоли число, где n может быть очень большим (до 10^18): http://pastebin.com/H9U5q6sr

Использую оптимизированный алгоритм с Q-матрицами: https://habrahabr.ru/post/148336/, возвожу в степень тоже быстро: по алгоритму быстрого возведения в степень.
Никаких циклов в вычислении элементов матрицы тоже нет.
Работает всё почему-то очень медленно (медленное умножение, как определил).
Не понимаю, почему так и как это фиксить. Кто сталкивался-посоветуйте, пожалуйста, как решить проблему.

```
public void bigfib(){
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    BigInteger n = sc.nextBigInteger();
    BigInteger m = sc.nextBigInteger();
    BigInteger [][] a = new BigInteger[][]{{BigInteger.ONE,BigInteger.ONE},{BigInteger.ONE,BigInteger.ZERO}};
    System.out.println(pow(a,n)[0][1].mod(m));
}

private BigInteger[][] mult(BigInteger[][] m1, BigInteger[][] m2) {
    BigInteger a = m1[0][0];
    BigInteger a2 = m2[0][0];
    BigInteger b = m1[0][1];
    BigInteger b2 =m2[0][1];
    BigInteger c = m1[1][0];
    BigInteger c2 = m2[1][0];
    BigInteger d = m1[1][1];
    BigInteger d2 =m2[1][1];
    BigInteger a11 = a.multiply(a2).add(b.multiply(c2));
    BigInteger a12 = a.multiply(b2).add(b.multiply(d2));
    BigInteger a21 = c.multiply(a2).add(d.multiply(c2));
    BigInteger a22 = c.multiply(b2).add(d.multiply(d2));
    BigInteger[][] mResult = new BigInteger[][]{{a11,a12},{a21,a22}};
    return mResult;
}

private BigInteger[][] pow(BigInteger a[][], BigInteger p) {
    BigInteger my2 = new BigInteger("2");
    BigInteger[][] result;

    if (p.equals(BigInteger.ONE))
        return a;

    if (p.equals(my2))
        return mult(a,a);

    if (p.mod(my2).equals(BigInteger.ONE)) {
        return mult(a,pow(a,p.subtract(BigInteger.ONE)));
    } else {
        result = pow(a,p.divide(my2));
        return mult(result,result);
    }
}
```

Comment: Реализация на `BigInteger` не будет быстрой по определению.

Comment: Хорошая новость в том, что вам вообще не нужно связываться с большими числами, так как на каждом шаге вы не должны получать результат , превосходящий `m`.

Comment: @Nofate, минутку, ща. Мне надо считать n, которое уж точно может быть до 10^18, т.е. везде юзать long?
Или  вы предлагаете не `pow(a,n)[0][1].mod(m)` делать, а  `return mult(a,pow(a,p.subtract(BigInteger.ONE))).mod(m)`?

Answer (score 0):

Решение с [wikibooks](https://ru.wikibooks.org/wiki/%D0%92%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB_%D0%A4%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D1%87%D0%B8#.D0.A0.D0.B5.D1.88.D0.B5.D0.BD.D0.B8.D0.B5_.D0.B1.D1.8B.D1.81.D1.82.D1.80.D1.8B.D0.BC_.D0.B2.D0.BE.D0.B7.D0.B2.D0.B5.D0.B4.D0.B5.D0.BD.D0.B8.D0.B5.D0.BC_.D0.BC.D0.B0.D1.82.D1.80.D0.B8.D1.86.D1.8B_.D0.B2_.D1.81.D1.82.D0.B5.D0.BF.D0.B5.D0.BD.D1.8C)

```
private static long fib(long n, long m) {
    long a = 1, b = 1, // матрица А
        c = 1, d = 0, // матрица А
        rc = 0, rd = 1, // вектор R
        ta, tb, tc;

    while (n > 0) {
        if ((n & 1) == 1) { // Если степень нечетная
            // Умножаем вектор R на матрицу A
            tc = rc;
            rc = (rc * a + rd * c) % m;
            rd = (tc * b + rd * d) % m;
        }

        // Умножаем матрицу A на саму себя
        ta = a;
        tb = b;
        tc = c;
        a = (a * a + b * c) % m;
        b = (ta * b + b * d) % m;
        c = (c * ta + d * c) % m;
        d = (tc * tb + d * d) % m;

        n >>= 1;  // Уменьшаем степень вдвое

    }
    return rc;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(fib(11527523930876953L, 26673)); // 10552
}
```

Comment: Видел очень похожий на c++...Посмотрим, тот лажал на больших числах (отрицательные остатки).
Я уже решил проблему, кстати, именно запихиванием деления по модулю в подсчёт элементов матрицы, всё работает.
В любом случае, большое спасибо за помощь:)